# Mongoose find function to search not returning desired results

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have a list of users in Mongodb that needs to searched according to some filters as shown in below picture:[Only gender is mandatory and users may or may not have other details](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xW8F3.png)

```
    User.find({
     "gender": userEntry.gender,
     "dob": { $gte: convert.getDobFromAge(userEntry.ageHigherLimit), $lte: convert.getDobFromAge(userEntry.ageLowerLimit), $exist: false },
     "details.chest": { $gte: userEntry.chestLowerLimit, $lte: userEntry.chestHigherLimit, $exist: false },
     "details.waist": { $gte: userEntry.waistLowerLimit, $lte: userEntry.waistHigherLimit, $exist: false },
     "details.height": { $gte: userEntry.heightLowerLimit, $lte: userEntry.heightHigherLimit, $exist: false },
     "details.weight": { $gte: userEntry.weightLowerLimit, $lte: userEntry.weightHigherLimit, $exist: false }
   },   function (err, users) {
          return res.render('client/search.html', { users: users });
   });
```

Above is the mongoose query to search and the userEntry looks like this

```
 userEntry={
  "gender":2,
  "ageLowerLimit":28,"ageHigherLimit":40,
  "chestLowerLimit":"","chestHigherLimit":"",
  "heightLowerLimit":"","heightHigherLimit":"",
  "waistLowerLimit":"","waistHigherLimit":"",
  "weightLowerLimit":"","weightHigherLimit":"",
  "state":"","city":"",
  "country":"","skin_color":"",
  "profession_type":"","experience":"",
  "hair_type":""
}
```

My problem is the find function , it should search all records with gender as '2' and age>=28 and age=<40 (from the above query gives me empty array even though one record satisfies it),giving all the results that satisfy the above conditions irrespective of whether other fields are empty or doesnot exist.
Any help would be appreciated.

As rightly suggested changed the query to but still 0 records fetched

```
var query = {
  details: {}
};
if (userEntry.gender) {
  query.gender = userEntry.gender;
}
if(userEntry.ageLowerLimit && userEntry.ageHigherLimit ) {
  query.dbo = { $gte: convert.getDobFromAge(userEntry.ageHigherLimit), $lte: convert.getDobFromAge(userEntry.ageLowerLimit)};
}
console.log(query);
User.find(query, function (err, users) {
  if(!err) {
    console.log(users);
    return res.render('client/search.html', { users: users });
  }
  console.log(err);
});
```

});

one of the records trying to fetch

```
{ "_id" : ObjectId("59c3f47e6388613b94556b78"), "name" : "tanzeel", "email" : "im_tanzeel@yahoo.co.in", "password" : "$2a$10$kvachEZL0vEPPJiS7bIAMeGMXiZ.MRaZmrBECXB207jme1I4JEn6i", "created_at" : ISODate("2017-09-21T17:18:54.822Z"), "role" : 1, "following" : [ ], "dp" : "/dp/default.jpg", "gender" : 2, "__v" : 0, "dob" : ISODate("1994-11-29T00:00:00Z"), "details" : {  "height" : 160, "weight" : 65, "profession_type" : "Actor", "skin_color" : "Tan", "eye_color" : "Black", "waist" : 32, "chest" : 35 } }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You got correct value from MongoDB but not your expected value because your query build not correct. Also `$exist` not valid operator should be `$exists` and you compare with empty string for some fields like `details.waist = ""` because `userEntry.weightLowerLimit` is empty. However you should build query correctly to get expected result. 
can try like this...

```
var query = {
  details: {}
};

if (userEntry.gender) {
  query.gender = userEntry.gender;
}
if(userEntry.ageLowerLimit && userEntry.ageHigherLimit ) {
  query.dbo = { $gte: convert.getDobFromAge(userEntry.ageHigherLimit), $lte: convert.getDobFromAge(userEntry.ageLowerLimit)};
}
if(userEntry.chestLowerLimit &&  userEntry.chestHigherLimit) {
  query['details.chest'] = { $gte: userEntry.chestLowerLimit, $lte: userEntry.chestHigherLimit };
}
//... for others conditions

User.find(query, function (err, users) {
  if(!err) {
    return res.render('client/search.html', { users: users });
  }
  console.log(err);
});
```

Comment: I tried the above answer, however now even for gender =2 getting 0 records(edited the question)

Comment: Changed query.details.waist to query['details.waist'] , to make it work , thanks